# Page Not Loading in Firefox after Authentication

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written Java code using Selenium Webdriver and AutoIt that opens a Firefox driver, navigates to a page that requires authentication via selection of a soft certificate, selects the appropriate certificate when the Certificate Selection window pops up, and clicks OK, at which point the page I'm accessing should load but instead it just loads a blank "New Tab"; a new tab isn't opened per se, just the current tab remains blank with the title of "New Tab".

If I perform this process manually (without having Selenium Webdriver open a Firefox driver and I just launch it myself) using the same exact Firefox profile, the page loads after authentication just fine.  I should also note that the page loads successfully using driver instances of Internet Explorer and Chrome.

I am using Firefox v33.1, IE 10, and Chrome v38.  Finally, I should note that this has nothing to do with my automated certificate selection process because even if I only have Selenium Webdriver open a Firefox driver and stop there and then I take the wheel and select the certificate myself and click OK, it still does the same thing.

I think Selenium Webdriver might have some annoying guard built into the Firefox drivers it instantiates that prevents it from loading pages requiring authentication.  If this is the case, does anyone know how to possibly disable that?

Comment: Are you able to run it on a different platform? (I'm guessing you are on Windows so run it on Linux or Mac OS.) Some bugs in Selenium are platform specific.

Comment: Unfortunately it has to work in the Windows platform.  I think it has something to do with Selenium Webdriver loading an "imitation" of the specified profile rather than the actual profile itself because when I go to the Firefox Troubleshooting Information and click "show Folder" next to Profile Folder, it directs me to a folder with a name like "anonymous90872345webdriver-profile" rather than the folder of the profile itself like it would if I manually opened Firefox.  All the bookmarks and installed certs are copied over but this isn't the actual profile folder clearly.

Comment: You misunderstood the intent of my comment: if it works fine on other platform but not in Windows, chances are that it is a bug in Selenium. I'm not saying you should switch over to another platform.

Comment: I wish I had time to deploy it to another platform but unfortunately I do not.  So when you specify a profile to open in your Firefox driver, it opens that exact profile and not an imitation of sorts?  Might help if we could verify that this is expected behavior.

Comment: By default it creates a *new* profile to run Firefox every time it starts a FF instance. This is normal.

Comment: So it always makes this "new" profile even if you specify a profile?  It will always make a new imitation profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java needed to be set to "Always Activate" under the Firefox Add-ons -> Plugins.  Before it was set to "Ask to Activate" but it never explicitly asked to activate after I selected the certificate, thus the page wouldn't load.