# How to Make Firefox Driver Same as if Firefox Manually Opened

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've noticed that opening Firefox with a profile using Selenium Webdriver has many differences from opening Firefox manually with the same exact profile.  The home page does not load in the Selenium Webdriver driver, non-boolean settings in about:config can't be modified ... to name a couple differences.  Is there a way to get Selenium Webdriver to open Firefox drivers to be exactly the same as if you opened Firefox manually?

EDIT: Here is my current code for sanity check purposes ...

```
        File profileDirectory = new File("C:\\Users\\[UserName]\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\cox74xm7.default");
        FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile(profileDirectory);
        WebDriver ffdriver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate [`FirefoxProfile`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile.html) and pass it to the `WebDriver` constructor:

```
File profileDirectory = new File(path);
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(profileDirectory);
WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

where `path` is a path to your existing profile.

Comment: Alright before I just passed the constructor a ProfilesIni profile object with a getProfile(profileName) but I switched it to specifically be a FirefoxProfile like you specified and it's still not working.  Interestingly enough, it still shows a temp folder of "anonymous90872345webdriver-profile" when I go into the Firefox Troubleshooting Information and click "Show Folder", which leads me to believe it's still copying over select profile pieces of my choice profile rather than using the exact profile itself.

Answer (score 1):

`FirefoxDriver` never launches the browser directly using a profile, even if passed in via the constructor using a `FirefoxProfile` object. A copy of the profile is always made by the driver. The reason for this is that the driver has to account for the use case of a user using the driver to execute multiple instances of Firefox using the same profile. Using the actual profile *in situ* would make this problematic for obvious reasons. When you pass an existing profile into the driver constructor, it should be copying the entire profile over into the temp directory, and using it as appropriate. Further note, however, that there are some profile settings that **must** be set with certain settings in order for the driver to function properly.

Comment: I posted this in another question and didn't get any helpful answers so I asked this question as a follow-up to try and lead to it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913518/page-not-loading-in-firefox-after-authentication   Do you know what profile settings would have to be set for me to access a page requiring authentication like I describe in my other question?